# Flash continually asking to update

Tags: windows-7, flash-player

Each time I boot into Windows, I get an update request from (my already updated to current) Adobe Flash. I'm seeing similar across a range of laptops and other Windows 7 installs.

Either Adobe is just pushing out that many minor updates that need to install every other week or so, or the updater is updating itself.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: How do you know it's the latest version? Have you checked against their site? Have you manually removed and reinstalled Flash, and were you able to reproduce the problem after doing so?

Comment: Just click the button - there are worse things in life.  You pressed many more buttons just typing your question!

Comment: I'm getting these update notes every other week or so - clearly either they are triggered on very minor version builds or something's bunged with the update mechanism. Either way it's abuse on Adobe's part - abusing my need to interact with them so often or buggy software updates. agreed....there _are worse things in life but Adobe's degradation of what Macromedia built deserves the scorn and outrage of the user base.

Answer (score 5):

There have been a few 0 day vulnerabilities, and Adobe have been pushing a few updates recently.

The fact that you have said "a range of laptops and other Windows 7 installs" make me think (with no insult to you) that you may have simply lost track of what has what.

If you want to check for any errors, you can uninstall Flash then reinstall it, (or just try to reinstall straight away), I would recommend you use the [Ninite](http://www.ninite.com) installer.

I have [prepared an installer for you here](http://ninite.com/flash-flashie/), which contains both the flash component for firefox/third party browsers and the IE component.

If this doesn't work, you really need to take [a look here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html), restart and try to update then confirm whether or not an update actually occurred.... If there is an error, please say and we will try to help you further.

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time i've lost track of stuff but in this case, no...either the updater is snagging on something or they are just pushing the update trigger way more often than they used to.